# always find the wireless mouse not to be that fast

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I use a laptop and I have used many types of mice. However, I always feel that the mouse is not that fast. Is there specific features for a wireless mouse that is fast or should I go with wired one?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What you want is largely personal preference. I had to slow down my new Logitech Bluetooth mouse .   Get specs on what you wish to obtain and make sure you can set it (speed up, slow down).

Comment: A wireless mouse that will usually have worse latency than an equivalent wired one.

Comment: It would depend on the PC's ability to handle a wireless mouse, and what you mean by "fast": Cursor latency? pixels per cm? Button latency?